# How to make sure that your application does't get banned from the Playstore

Tags: android

I am about to put my first application on the playstore.I want to ask ..How to make sure that my application is not banned from the Playstore?Also,If my application gets banned does it mean my account on the playstore permanently suspended,What about other applications if I somebody has and he gets his application banned.I have a religious application in which I have put an image which I did't draw my self but clicked it from a picture I have in my home.I could't find a similar image in the top google results.I think I am infringing a copyright law of the person who would have created that image and got it printed and sold the copies physically and I have made an electronic copy of that.Please put some light on my doubts..Thank you..

Comment: Please note that copying an image from google search results does not prevent you from being in breach of copyright for the image in question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can give you some guidelines that will come close. 1. follow the play store rules to the letter; 2. don't breach copyright or even come close to looking as if you will. You would fall foul of number 2 based on your own admission. Remove the picture or get permission from the copyright owner and follow their requirements (on acknowledging copyright) to the letter.

I have difficulty believing that the success or otherwise of your app is hinging on a single picture. I'd just find a replacement. iStockphoto or similar? Quick trip to local religeous establishment?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Google Play's [terms of service](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) to determine if it will or won't be banned. Based on what you have said, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Banned no. Pulled maybe, in response to a takedown request due to copyright breach - although the likelihood of that will be dependent on how well known the image is and how strictly the copyright owner enforces their rights.

Comment: I am 100 percent sure the actual owner is not going to google for that as the chances are high that he will never actually know or may be even remember that he created it .That image is of a hindu god and similar image is found in almost every home of hindus and every temple .Also I dont expect that application to do an awesome business out there.I am launching it just to see how things work.It is a very basic app.I am just being little extra conscious because I just don't want to get banned in any case..Thank you for your response.That was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Comply with [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html) and you'll be perfectly fine.

Comment: Making it free won't avoid a copyright infringment claim.

Comment: You're right, this is much more complicated.

Comment: For clarity, g00dy's answer originally stated that giving an app away for free would avoid copyright issues. Which it doesn't. But somebody has now edited that part out (a correction, leaving the original statement in, would have been better).